# Laravel 5.5, разворачивание дампа базы

Tags: php, laravel

Доброе утро. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть дамп базы в виде 1 таблицы с заполненными данными (этот файл лежит на компьютере), как мне его развернуть в laravel ? нужно ли создавать миграцию под эту таблицу, или при разворачивание дампа , она автоматически создастся ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто заливайте его как обычный дамп, Laravel тут не при чём, за наполнение данных в базу в Laravel отвечают [Seeds](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding), если хотите залить дамп через команду `php artisan db:seed` то создаете сидер и туда код с файла перемещаете.

Если вопрос чисто в том создавать таблицу или нет - посмотрите в дампе, если там есть создание таблицы то ничего создавать не нужно, если в файле только импорт данных - создайте миграцию чисто для создания таблицы.